# How to copy color of the conditional formatting cell to another excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, colors

On one sheet I have a data which has conditional formatting color.

I want to copy and paste that into another file, I was able to paste value, column width etc. but I couldn't paste the color from the conditional formatting.

I researched and the suggestion was to paste it in word and then back to excel but that ruins my excel row and column formatting.

How to do that? Is it possible?

[image: sample image]

Comment: Open 2 Workbook in the same instance, then you can copy format color to another workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would like to suggest you two possible methods. One is Non-programming & Second is Programming(VBA Macro).**

**Non-Programming Method:**

1. Open both Workbooks.
2. Copy a cell from the **original Workbook's 
   Sheet**, (from where you want to Copy the 
   Conditional Formatting) to an unused position 
   in the **destination Workbook's sheet**.
3. Open the **Manage Rules** option of 
   **Conditional Formatting**.
4. Select **Show formatting rules** for This 
   Worksheet.
5. For each Rule, adjust the **Applies to** match 
   the range you require.
6. Click the **Range button** to the right of the 
   **Applies to.**
7. Click-drag-select from the top left cell to 
   the bottom right cell.
8. Click the **Range button** to return to the Conditional Rules Manager.
9. Click **OK** or **Apply** to get the 
   result.

**Programming Method:**

1. At Source File press `Alt+F11` to 
    open the VB Editor.
2. Copy & paste this code as Standard 
    module.

   ```
   Sub CopyFormat()
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="source.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3)
   wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H100").Copy
   Selection.PasteSpecial _ 
   Paste:=xlPasteValues
   Selection.PasteSpecial _ 
   xlPasteFormats

   wbSource.Close
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End Sub
   ```

**Note:**

1. You can edit Worbook & Sheet name as 
   per your need.
2. Adjust cell references for the Copied 
   Range as needed.

Answer (score 9):

If you do not need the formula for the conditional formatting, if you copy it to MS Word and back to Excel the color should be copied as well.

Comment: I needed this because I was changing ratings from numbers to words for a management meeting. So I wanted the colors from conditional formatting, but couldn't use it. So I copied to Word, then a blank spot in Excel, then copied and pasted formats only back to table I wanted the colors on. Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

I found a dead easy solution to this problem.

1. Copy the cells with the results of conditional formatting that you want to duplicate in another place.
2. Paste into an OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet (I used build 4.1.5) as Formatted - RTF. The formatting is still there, but OpenOffice apparently discards the conditions that created the formatting in the first place.
3. Now simply copy and paste into Excel.
4. Crack open the champagne.

This works with Excel files thousands of lines long.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste as html into a new instance of Excel might be the easiest way.
You can open a new instance of Excel by Right-click on Excel icon > Press and hold the ALT key > click Excel 201* > continue to press the ALT key until you receive the prompt "Do you want to start a new instance of Excel". Then select YES.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My method:
Copy to Google Spreadsheet, copy the cells, and paste them back into Excel - this copy colors.